# R - Impossible to install R package 'bizdays'

Tags: r, bizdays

I am looking to install bizdays package for R. I tried the traditional method, and the one below, with not much success.
Can someone please help to understand why this specific package cannot get installed but all the others are going through OK.

I get the following logs:

```
> devtools::install_github('wilsonfreitas/R-bizdays')
Downloading GitHub repo wilsonfreitas/R-bizdays@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/wilsonfreitas/R-bizdays/zipball/master
Installing bizdays
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/z9/vfdjnsxx5zv15kdvfdy65trh0000gn/T/RtmpPTQIDE/devtoolsb4365b7ed46d/wilsonfreitas-R-bizdays-5685a08'  \
  --library='/Users/Mood/Library/R/3.2/library' --install-tests 

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 261: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 261: exec: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R: cannot execute: No such file or directory
Installation failed: Command failed (126)
```

Comment: I assume this is OSX. How did you install R? Does `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R` exist? What's "the traditional method" and what was the error with that - the same?

Comment: It looks like you're using R 3.2, which is several years old.  Maybe update to a newer version, restart R, and try installing the regular way.

Comment: hey guys, sure, let me do now. Thank you